# Could not install ruby 1.9.2 with RVM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

Google was not very useful trying to find what is wrong.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for smf, might require sudo password.
Installing SM Framework.
Error running 'requirements_smf_install_sm',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1369014444_smf_install.log
```

The log file says the following:

```
[2013-05-19 22:47:24] requirements_smf_install_sm
SMF Framework support is only intended for RailsInstaller, please use Homebrew integration instead.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I had:

```
rvm autolibs smf
```

in /etc/rvmrc

I removed it, then I executed

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Then I did

```
rvm autolibs brew
```

and finally

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

worked!

Comment: After you answered your own question, please mark the answer as accepted, to prevent folks willing to help from visiting this unanswered question.